# Host WCF in a Windows Service Using TCP, Got "there was no endpoint listening..." error

Tags: wcf, net.tcp

I am trying the msdn walk through example:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

and at the end when I try to add service reference with address: net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1, it returns me this error:

The URI prefix is not recognized.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1'.
There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service1 that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

I did fix the error inside the example that others mention and use this line instead:
myServiceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(WCFServiceHost.Service1));

Comment: Put your tried code here. Let's see.

Comment: Sent you a email.